# "Partially" init a git flow repo

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-flow

I have a cloned repo I wanna commit to using git flow, but it's not initialized as a git flow repo and it has no branches like 'release' or 'hotfix'.

Can I somehow "partially" initialize it as a git flow repo?
I mean, I actually need only '`develop`' branch and branches for my features, but when I run `git flow init` it also asks for release branch, hotfix branch (maybe smth more, don't remember) which I actually don't need and refuses to init the repo if some of those branches is absent.

I don't need those branches and I don't wanna create them, 'cause I don't wanna pollute the repo with branches created only to satisfy git flow.

Can I somehow init the git flow repo with only develop branch and features branches prefix?
Or what is the common solution for such case?

Answer (score 1):

`git flow init` does not actually create any release, hotfix or feature branches, because as opposed to the develop and master branch, these are **not** single, everlasting branches. They are created as feature/abc, release/42.0 or hotfix/foo for every feature, hotfix or realease you create, and are merged and then deleted once you finish.

What `git flow init` actually asks for is the prefix for naming these branches, which means you can just pass it the default values for release, hotfix and feature without worrying about polluting your repo, as it will not create any branches until you specifically ask it to start a feature, hotfix or release.

You can read up on these concepts in the [official explanation of git flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)

Comment: ok, what if I even haven't `master` branch in that repo, just `develop`?

Comment: Git flow does require a master branch to work, because thats where it merges released and hotfixes. If you don't have a master and don't want to create release and hotfix branches, you might want to forget using git flow and create your feature branches yourself, because git flow does nothing but create branches with a standardized name when starting a feature, and merging them back into develop and then deleting them when finishing it - theres no magic inside, just raw git commands

Answer (score 0):

Consider this [comparison of using `git flow` commands versus raw `git` commands](https://gist.github.com/JamesMGreene/cdd0ac49f90c987e45ac):

`git flow init` is similar to:

```
git init
git commit --allow-empty -m "Initial commit"
git checkout -b develop master
```

(it also add to your config gitflow-specific settings:

```
[gitflow "branch"]
    master = master
    develop = develop
[gitflow "prefix"]
    feature = feature/
    release = release/
    hotfix = hotfix/
    support = support/
    versiontag =
```

)

If you don't have `master`, you can first create it from your current develop branch.

```
git checkout -b master develop
```

Comment: if i push to remote won't it pollute the remote repo with that empty branch?